# Can I have more than 1 sf::Clock instance? (How does sf::Clock work?)

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using `sf::Clock` to control a loop.

I want to know whether I am allowed to use more than 1 `sf::Clock`, and if I do, whether all the "clocks" will be well behaved and work as expected *on all operating systems*.

For example:

```
sf::Clock c1;
sf::Clock c2;

while(1)
{
    std::cout << c1.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() << ", " << c2.restart().asSeconds() << std::endl;
}
```

Or will some unexpected behaviour result?

On Linux, this appears to work, with the following output:

```
4e-06, 1e-06
2.00026, 2.00025
4.00039, 2.00014
6.00053, 2.00014
8.00066, 2.00013
10.0008, 2.00011
```

I can't test this on Mac OS X or Windows however. (And just because it works in the test program I wrote doesn't mean it will work for any number of clocks. My example just demonstrates that it appears to work for 2.)

Any information on how `sf::Clock` is implemented would be useful here.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from creating as many `sf::Clock`s as you like. It is really just a thin wrapper around [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows, [`mach_absolute_time`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html) on Mac, and [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) on Posix compatible OS's.

Comment: @SeanCline If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine, you can have as many instances as you fancy. There's no restriction on that.